# setState to array based on the server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data structure in my state

```
this.state = {
days: [
                { day: "Monday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Tuesday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Wednesday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Thursday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Friday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Saturday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
                { day: "Sunday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
            ],
}
```

I am expecting a response from the server with the same format `availabilities` array (coming from props).

If the day of the received array matches, I want to overwrite and setState to only those days that get returned. The rest to stay the same. For example if the response is:

```
 { day: "Monday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
```

I want to setState to the first element of my days array and overwrite fromHour, toHour, fromMin, toMin and set available to true. Here's my below, and the setState where I am currently stuck. Help or suggestions?

```
setAvailabilities() {
    const { availabilities } = this.props;
    const { days } = this.state;
    const weekday = [];
    const daysAailable = [];


    for (i = 0; i < availabilities.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {
            if (days[j].day === availabilities[i].day) {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state.days,
//stuck here
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastructure for your state is:

```
interface State {
    days: Day[]
}
```

But inside the `this.setState` call, you're spreading the array across the state instead of replacing the array. So you would end up with something like this:

```
state = {
     days: [...],
     0: { day: "Monday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
     1: { day: "Tuesday", fromHour: 11, fromMin: 30, toHour: 17, toMin: 30, available: false },
     // etc...
}
```

Anyway...

Instead of calling `this.setState` for each updated day, I would recommend constructing a new array and set the entire date array at once:

```
setAvailabilities() {
    const { availabilities } = this.props;
    const { days } = this.state;

    const nextDays = [...days]

    for (i = 0; i < availabilities.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nextDays.length; j++) {
            if (nextDays[j].day === availabilities[i].day) {
                nextDays[j] = availabilities[i]
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState({ days: newDays })
}
```